# Getting attribute value using XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file like this

```
<Program xmlns="CBOpenIFSchema3_0">
    <Variables/>
    <CodeBlocks>
        <CodeBlock Name="Code1">
            <Code>
                Sample code 1
            </Code>
        </CodeBlock>
        <CodeBlock Name="Code2">
            <Code>
                Sample code 2
            </Code>
        </CodeBlock>
        <CodeBlock Name="Code3">
            <Code>
                Sample code 3
            </Code>
        </CodeBlock>
    </CodeBlocks>
</Program>
```

From this xml I need to get the name of each codeblock and the code corresponding to it. How can this be done using XElement? I tried using the following.

```
XElement xDoc = XElement.Load("test.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> codeBlocks = xDoc.Descendants("CodeBlocks").Elements();
foreach (var c in codeBlocks)
    Console.WriteLine(c.Attribute("Name").Value);
```

`codeBlocks` is showing `"Enumeration yielded no results"`.

Edit: `xmlns="CBOpenIFSchema3_0"` gives the problem.

Comment: is this your read XML in `test.xml`? your code working fine for me

Comment: @Sreeja try again. it seems ok. Just check the test.xml file that your programm is suppose to use. and also check your projects output directory.

Comment: Sorry an error while copy-pasting the xml. Edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document uses default XML namespace, so you have to use one within your query:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("source.txt");
var ns = XNamespace.Get("CBOpenIFSchema3_0");

var codeBlocks = xDoc.Root.Element(ns + "CodeBlocks").Elements(ns + "CodeBlock");
foreach (var c in codeBlocks)
    Console.WriteLine((string)c.Attribute("Name"));
```

I've also made some changes to your code:

- use `XDocument` to load XML document
- use [XAttribute Explicit Conversion (XAttribute to String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339184.aspx) instead of `XAttribute.Value` property
- [don't use `Descendants` method unless your XML contains tree-like structure](http://mjuraszek.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-not-use-descendants-method.html)

Comment: Can you please tell me why do you suggest XDocument when both XElement and XDocument works fine? Is it the best practice?

Comment: Is your XML a document? So use class that is designed to deal with document. There is additional XML validation when you're using `XDocument`.

Comment: An XDocument is rarely needed, an XElement as root works fine in most cases.

Comment: And you could have used `var ns = xDoc.GetDefaultNameSapce();`